# Ruby on Rails bundler: command not found: spring unable to proceed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
run  bundle install --local
```

Could not find `gem 'rails (= 4.2.6)'` in any of the gem sources listed in your
Gemfile.

```
run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

> bundler: command not found: spring Install missing gem executables
>   with `bundle install`

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Could you give more details on this?

Comment: include your gemfile

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have Rails version different version of Rails(Its clear that you don't have 4.2.6 installed) installed(your rails project directory), but apparently you has updated it and now your project requires version 4.2.6. Update your gems:

bundle install